# Fit a Decision Tree classifier to the data; Error in code

Tags: r, decision-tree

This is the code I entered into RStudio to create a decision tree, and `park` is a data frame I have in my environment

```
people <- park %>%
  select(Subj, Parkinson, fhi, jitter, rap, shimmer, apq, nhr) %>%
  na.omit()
glimpse(people)
tally(~ Parkinson, data = people, format = "percent")  # simple table


################
set.seed(1688)
#############

# Tree with rpart
whoHasPark <- rpart(Parkinson ~ Subj, fhi, jitter,
                        data = people, control = rpart.control(cp = 0.005, minbucket = 30))
whoHasPark
plot(as.party(whoHasPark))
```

This is the error I got back:

> Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) :
>   'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Where is `park` supposed to come from? And what exactly are you trying to plot? What should the desired output look like?

Comment: @MrFlick `park` is the data frame I am pulling from my environment. I am just looking for a decision tree to be created in the plot

Comment: As mentioned below by Vashi, the first argument of rpart is a formula and the terms (predictors) must be separated by "+" (not by ",")

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but that could be because you are giving `Parkinson ~ Subj, fhi, jitter`(separating them by comma throws an error) in your rpart call. Trying with '+' might help `Parkinson ~ Subj + fhi + jitter`.