# Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) while knitting the file

Tags: r

I have everything working when I  run the chunks but an error occurs when I decide to knit my `.rmd` file

```
########### needed for testing purpose #################

library(tree)
set.seed(77191)


library(ISLR)
library(randomForest)
attach(Carseats)
n=nrow(Carseats)
indices=sample(1:n,n/2,replace=F)
cstrain=Carseats[indices,]
cstest=Carseats[-indices,]

tree.cs <- tree(Sales ~. , data = cstrain)
summary(tree.cs)
plot(tree.cs)
text(tree.cs)
y_hat <-predict(tree.cs, newdata = cstest)
test.mse =mean((y_hat - cstest$Sales)^2)  #Test's MSE
test.mse
######################################################

# 2nd chunk
cv.cs <- cv.tree(tree.cs)
cx =cv.cs$size
cy =cv.cs$dev
mymy <- xy.coords(cx,cy)
plot(mymy, xlab = "size", ylab = "dev",  type = "b")
mini.tree <-which.min(cv.cs$dev)
points(mini.tree,cv.cs$dev[mini.tree], col="green", cex= 2, pch = 20)
```

2nd chunk Yields :[image: ![enter image description here]

```
#3rd chunk
#pruning
prune.cs <- prune.tree(tree.cs, best = mini.tree)
plot(prune.cs) # the problematic part

y_hat <- predict(prune.cs, newdata = cstest)

mean((y_hat - cstest$Sales)^2)
```

The 3rd chunk has to yield something similar  to this:
[image]
Not a duplicate of:

['x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004068/x-is-a-list-but-does-not-have-components-x-and-y)

[Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38049152/error-in-xy-coordsx-y-xlabel-ylabel-log-x-is-a-list-but-does-not-have)

Did not solve the problem:

[Fit a Decision Tree classifier to the data; Error in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47190465/fit-a-decision-tree-classifier-to-the-data-error-in-code?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I know about the coordinates plot() needs in order to run but here  I am trying to plot a tree. Also, it worked many times before but wouldn't just knit the file.

1st chuck is added in case you want to try it by yourself.

Thank you.

Comment: Tried to run you code, but couldn't find `tree.cs` in `cv.cs <- cv.tree(tree.cs)`

Comment: Just added the rest of the code. @markhogue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose your problematic line should be

```
prune.cs <- prune.tree(tree.cs, best = cv.cs$size[mini.tree])
```

instead of

```
prune.cs <- prune.tree(tree.cs, best = mini.tree)
```

You are not interested in the index, which can change every time you do cross-validation, but the tree size at that index.

The same thing is true in the 2nd chunk where you have

```
points(mini.tree,cv.cs$dev[mini.tree], col="green", cex= 2, pch = 20)
```

which should be

```
points(cv.cs$size[mini.tree], cv.cs$dev[mini.tree], col="green", cex= 2, pch = 20)
```

Comment: could you expand just a little on the tree size at index to nail down the conceptual difference. Thx.

Comment: `which.min(cv.cs$dev)` gives you the index at which cv.cs$dev is minimal. `cv.cs$size[mini.tree]` gives you the number of terminal nodes where cv.cs$dev is minimal, which is what you want to pass on as `best`. You want to prune your tree to that size, not to 1, if cv.cs$dev[1] is minimal.